# How to add data to an existing excel file in python without overwriting the data

Tags: pandas, csv, xlsx

I have a master excel sheet where the data looks like this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS4cw.png

I have a script which imports the csv files and combines them and save it to the master excel sheet.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)
files = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True) 
%gui tk
var = root.tk.splitlist(files)
filePaths = []
for f in var:
    df = pd.read_csv(f,skiprows=8, index_col=None, header='infer',parse_dates=True, squeeze=True, encoding='ISO-8859–1',names=['Date', 'Time', 'Temperature', 'Humidty'])
    filePaths.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(filePaths, axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index=True, sort=True) 
    book = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Hebin\Scripts\Temperature Distribution chart/july/12.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Hebin\Scripts\Temperature Distribution chart/july/12.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    df.to_excel(writer, "Sheet1", columns=['Date', 'Time','Temperature', 'Humidty'],index=False)
    writer.save()
```

The problem is that the newly imported data is saved from row 1 instead of starting at the ending row of the previously saved data. How can I save the data in an orderly manner everytime without entering the row number?

Answer (score 0):

The [ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) can have its mode set to either write ('w') or append ('a'). The default is write.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Hebin\Scripts\Temperature Distribution chart/july/12.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
```